Entity Framework not saving data into database
I made a simple app where you can give the program xml files and it pairs the products inside them by manufacturer part number, but it is not saving it into the db, however if the product  is already exists in the database or I run the script a second time, it works perfectly!
Code:
public async Task ImportChsData(DateTime fromDateTime)
{
    var chsCikkek = new List<Cikk>();

    #if DEBUG
    chsCikkek = DeserializeChsResponse(await GetStringFromUrlAsync("######"));
    #else
    //#####
    #endif

    var existingTermekek = await _appDbContext.Termekek
            .Include(t => t.Arak)
            .Include(t => t.Keszletek)
            .Include(t => t.NagykerCikkszamok)
            .ToDictionaryAsync(t => t.GyartoiCikkszam, t => t);

    var newTermekek = new List<Termek>();
    var updatedTermekek = new List<Termek>();
    var chsdeletelista = new List<string>();

    foreach (var chsCikk in chsCikkek)
    {
        if (chsCikk.Webmegjel == "2" && existingTermekek.TryGetValue(chsCikk.Gycikkszam, out var termek))
        {
            // Ha a termék törlendő a rendszerből
            if (termek.Arak.Any(a => a.ArTipus == "CHS"))
            {
                chsdeletelista.Add(termek.GyartoiCikkszam);
            }

            continue;
        }

        if (existingTermekek.TryGetValue(chsCikk.Gycikkszam, out var existingTermek))
        {
            // Nagyker cikkszám hozzáadása, ha még nincs
            var nagykerCikkszam = existingTermek.NagykerCikkszamok.FirstOrDefault(nc => nc.Nagyker == "CHS");

            if (nagykerCikkszam == null)
            {
                existingTermek.NagykerCikkszamok.Add(new NagykerCikkszam
                    {
                        Nagyker = "CHS",
                        Cikkszam = chsCikk.Cikkszam
                    });
            }

            updatedTermekek.Add(existingTermek);
        }
        else
        {
            // Új termék létrehozása
            await _kategoriaService.AddSzulokategoriaTask(chsCikk.Cikkcsoportnev, chsCikk.Focsoportnev);
            var newTermek = new Termek
                {
                    Nev = chsCikk.Cikknev,
                    Kategoria = await _kategoriaService.GetKategoriaByName(chsCikk.Cikkcsoportnev),
                    KategoriaId = (await _kategoriaService.GetKategoriaByName(chsCikk.Cikkcsoportnev)).id,
                    GyartoiCikkszam = chsCikk.Gycikkszam,
                    Gyarto = chsCikk.Gyarto,
                };

            if (newTermek.NagykerCikkszamok == null)
            {
                newTermek.NagykerCikkszamok = new List<NagykerCikkszam>();
            }

            newTermek.NagykerCikkszamok.Add(new NagykerCikkszam(){Cikkszam = chsCikk.Cikkszam, Nagyker = "CHS", Termek = newTermek});

            newTermekek.Add(newTermek);
        }
    }

    // Bulk updates and inserts
    if (updatedTermekek.Any())
    {
        await _appDbContext.BulkUpdateAsync(updatedTermekek);
    }

    if (newTermekek.Any())
    {
        await _appDbContext.BulkInsertAsync(newTermekek);
    }

    await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    if (chsdeletelista.Count > 0)
    {
        await _keszletService.RemoveTermek("CHS", chsdeletelista);
    }
}

Model class:
public class NagykerCikkszam
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Nagyker { get; set; }
    public string? Cikkszam { get; set; }
    public int TermekId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TermekId")]
    public Termek Termek { get; set; }
}

And I have this line in the Termek class:
public ICollection<NagykerCikkszam> NagykerCikkszamok { get; set; } = new List<NagykerCikkszam>();

I use SQL Server as my database.
Also, the ár is not saved neither when using BulkInsertAsync, but it saves when i use the BulkUpdateAsync
EDIT:
You can see that there should be 1 NagykerCikkszam for the product:

But in the next function this line of code:
            var existingTermekek = await _appDbContext.Termekek
                .Include(t => t.Keszletek)
                .Include(t => t.NagykerCikkszamok)
                .Where(t => t.NagykerCikkszamok.Any(nc => nc.Nagyker == "CHS" && nc.Cikkszam != null))
                .ToDictionaryAsync(
                    t => t.NagykerCikkszamok.First(nc => nc.Nagyker == "CHS").Cikkszam,
                    t => t
                );

returns NULL and also there is nothing in the db


also, the ár is not saved neither when using BulkInsertAsync

You should try to create a minimal reproducible example, it might also help you solve the problem yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

In addition to the minimal reproduceable example, please also edit your question and include debugging details. At what point in your code are you not getting the result you expect?

Hello!
So changing await _appDbContext.BulkInsertAsync(newTermekek); to await _appDbContext.Termekek.AddRangeAsync(newTermekek); solved it, but does it has any impact on the performance?

This program needs to update, add and list up to 200000 Termekek (products). Will it work fast? Or should i change to a different db engine?

Depends on how often you are inserting 200000 products. If you're doing it as a one-off, then I wouldn't worry too much about it. If you're doing it regularly, then you may want to look at using Dapper, as that will be faster than SQL Server. Changing the db engine is unlikely to help, as SQL Server is pretty fast, probably as fast as any other, faster than many.
